# How can I make a section in NSIS unchecked by default

Tags: nsis

I have a NSIS installer, here I have some components that user can choose to install:

```
Section "Modules" SecModules
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  CreateDirectory $INSTDIR\modules
  ...
SectionEnd

Section "Freenode util" SecFreenode
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  CreateDirectory $INSTDIR\modules
  ...
SectionEnd
```

how can I make the second one unchecked? By default they all are checked

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
; unselected because it is /o
Section /o "Modules" SecModules
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  CreateDirectory $INSTDIR\modules
  ...
SectionEnd

; selected
Section "Freenode util" SecFreenode
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  CreateDirectory $INSTDIR\modules
  ...
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Don't remember you should [accept your own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it) if you think it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 7):

Apart from [Section /o](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/Section), you can also use [SectionIn](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/SectionIn) to control default sections. The latter might be useful if you have several sections and you plan to offer several installation types (see [InstType](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/InstType)). Lastly, you can control the state of a section based on logic, using [SectionSetFlags](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/SectionSetFlags).

Comment: I fail to understand how could I use that for my purpose. I want to have a list of optional components and some of them should be installed by default and some of them only if user check them. I don't understand what is SectionIn good for in that case